# Accessing data object from multiple tkinter frames

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, customtkinter

## What I'm doing

I'm writing a graph-viewing app. The user opens the app, clicks 'Import' in the sidebar, chooses a CSV file and then sees the graph embedded in the app. The user then clicks 'Slice' in the sidebar, and the app detects regions of the graph (eg: phase 1 is from x=10 to x=20). The user may then adjust the regions, using a set of Entry widgets underneath the graph, if they feel the app has done it incorrectly. Lastly, the user clicks 'Export' and chooses where to save the file. The app saves a duplicate of the CSV file that was imported at the start, with flags added to mark the regions.

[This is the interface I have designed so far, with an artists impression of the soon-to-exist graph added for effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTZpX.png)

## What I've done so far

I've finished the interface layout, shown above. I've tried to follow a clear structure of classes. I have an `App.py` file, which contains an instance of the `main_window` class. That contains an instance of the `sidebar` class and `main frame` class. The `sidebar` class contains four instances of the `sidebar_button` class, etc etc. Note that I'm actually using customtkinter instead of tkinter, so it looks nicer. But I don't think that should change anything important.

Also, yes I know that the class `tkinter.Button` exists and so it may seem weird that I've defined my own `sidebar_button` class. I've just done it that way because all four sidebar buttons have the same visual properties (colour, highlight colour, corner radius etc) and I was trying to avoid duplicate code. My `sidebar_button` class is merely a subclass of `tkinter.Button`.

I've also started writing my `data` class, which contains the property `df` (a pandas dataframe) and methods such as `import`, `slice` and `export`.

## What's confusing me

I've read that its good to keep frontend and backend separate, which is why I've written the `data` class. The app should contain a single instance of this class, which GUI objects can access. However, all the GUI objects are sorted neatly into different classes, so I'm not sure how they can access the `data` object. I think I should instantiate the `data` object inside of the root tkinter object (my `main_window` object) or possibly in the higher-level file `App.py` (where `main_window` is instantiated). But then how would an object such as the Import button access the `data.import` method? The Import button is a `sidebar_button` object, instantiated inside of the `sidebar` object, which is instantiated inside of the `main_window` object. Maybe I have to pass the `data` object down through the hierarchy of objects? Ie: pass `data` to the `main_window` object, and then pass it from there to the `sidebar` object, and then to the `sidebar_button` object? It seems messy to me, but maybe I'm wrong. What is the proper way? Note that I cannot simply instantiate the `data` object inside of a `sidebar_button` object, because it needs to be accessed by lots of other GUI objects in the app.

## One other question, about handles vs values

Also, am I right in thinking that I have to pass the handle for my `data` object rather than the value, since I want all of the GUI objects that access `data` to be reading from and making adjustments to the same dataframe, that is contained within it?

I tried setting `data` as a global variable, but this didn't work because each of my classes are defined in a different file for neatness. I started researching this method a bit more and got the sense that it was not the 'proper' way to go about things.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for recommendations, rather than an "failed attempt" in a program. However, I can clearly see that OP has given the required effort to ask a "good question" even if it's off topic. So I'll respond with some hints to their problem. 1) consider [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) 2) every widget should have access to the root via `root = widget._root()`. This should help to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Having a read now. For future, where should I post similar questions that ask for recommendations?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, it is a research part for me. You can ask something like this in discord, reddit, quora and what not, but don't set your expectation high here. It is a opinion what you are ask for and not every opinion is qualified and many have one. However, you also can go ahead and write a program and ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272438/228833) where I have got similar input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the `master` property, as shown in the reduced example below. I don't know if this is the best or 'proper' approach, but it seems fairly neat to me.

Firstly, I instantiated the `data` and `sidebar` objects in the constructor for my `Main_window` class.

```py
class Main_window(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create data object
        self.data = Data()

        # create sidebar
        self.sidebar = Sidebar(self)
```

Secondly, I instantiated the three `sidebar_button` objects in the `Sidebar` class constructor.

```py
class Sidebar(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master) 

        # create buttons
        import_button = Sidebar_button(self,"Import",command=master.data.import_CSV)
        slice_button  = Sidebar_button(self,"Slice", command=master.data.auto_slice)
        export_button = Sidebar_button(self,"Export",command=master.data.export_CSV)
```

When I call the `sidebar` object constructor, I pass `main_window` to `master` using the `self` keyword. This means I can access the `main_window` object from the `sidebar` object.

I want to program the app so that the user can import a CSV file by clicking the 'Import' button. This button is inside of the `sidebar`, which is inside of the `main_window`. The method for loading a CSV file belongs to the `data` object, which is also inside of the `main_window`. So, inside of the `sidebar` constructor, I call the `sidebar_button` constructor and pass `command=master.data.import_CSV`. This is like passing `command=main_window.data.import_CSV`, because `main_window` is the `master` of `sidebar`.

For objects in my app that are more deeply nested, I simply used `master.master.master` etc. This seems messy to me, but I don't know of a better way.